# Configuration in WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a `context.xml` in Tomcat:

```
<Resource name="datasource/sconfiguration" auth="Container" connectionString=...
```

And I am able to get my object filled like:

```
MyConfiguration sc = (MyConfiguration) envCtx.lookup("datasource/sconfiguration");
```

Now I want to use my WAR in Glassfish 4.1... and it seem it doesn't work:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'datasource/sconfiguration' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterpr ....
```

It seems quite weird to have a WAR for a specific app server. How can I make this WAR valid for any WAS? It seems Glassfish [can use context.xml](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/geurd/index.html) but many people say it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Administrative stuff is not part of the standard WAR.  To be honest, it's always the hardest part in porting between application servers.

In Tomcat you can define JNDI datasources in the context.xml as you've seen.  I've long since abandoned Glassfish but I know that there is a fairly complete UI to define data sources.  Other application servers like WildFly have both a UI and a CLI to define things like data sources (and Glassfish may have that too).

Why is this you ask?  Because each application server is allowed to augment areas such as database connection pooling.  Tomcat has recently decided to get rid of commons DBCP pooling in favor of an internal pool.  Because of these differences, each application server defines a bit of a different way to configure JDBC connections and datasources.

To manage this you'll need setup scripts / pre-configured config files for each of the application servers you intend to target.  An end user will need to use what is appropriate for their environment.

Comment: I need to create a WAR file that can run in different WAS without changing my code. I am using a NoSql database with possibility to use different data sources (including SQL) so I need to define a generic object. I am now testing Glassfish and tried the JNDI but it seems slightly different, it couldnt find java:comp/env... just wondering if there is a clean, standard way in Java for registering my data, so not only Tomcat can read it

Comment: You won't need to change your code but you will need to either provide instructions or a shell script or something external to configure the database connection.  Some application servers also require copying the JDBC driver to a particular directory so that is a consideration too.  I'm afraid it isn't purely download and run.